# cannot work multiplication in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

i create a page which two textbox automatically multiply show result in another textbox. But it not working.

Javascript for multiplication......

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#dataTable').on('keyup', '.price', calTotal)
                  .on('keyup', '.quantity', calTotal);

// find the value and calculate it

    function calTotal() {
        var $row = $(this).closest('tr'),
            price    = $row.find('.price').val(),
            quantity = $row.find('.quantity').val(),
            total    = price * quantity;

// change the value in total

        $row.find('.txt').val(total)
    }

});
</script>
```

the html and php code is...

```
    <table border="1" id="dataTable">

    <tr>
    <th> Id</th>
    <th>p</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>M</th>
    <th>D</th>
    <th>De</th>
    <th>Q</th>
    <th>T</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    echo"<p></p>";
    echo"<p></p>";
    echo"<p></p>";
    echo"<p><h3> Details</h3></p>";
          $order = "SELECT * FROM abd ";
          $result = mysql_query($order);

         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
         {
$p= $row['p'];
  $b=$row['b'];
  $m= $row['m'];
  $dp=$row['price'];
  $q=$row['quantity'];


        echo "<td><input type=text value=$id name=item[] readonly=readonly /></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=text id=p name=p[] value=$p ></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=text id=B name=b[] value=$b ></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=text id=M name=m[] value=$m ></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=text id=Q name=qua[] value=$qua ></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=text id=price name=price[] value=$price class=price ></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=text id=Quantity name=q value=$q class=quantity ></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=text id=txt name=txt  class=txt  > </td>";
    ?>
    </table>
```

when i enter dprice and quantity it automatically show the value in total price.
But It not working.Please Help

Comment: use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` for values before multiplying. Also you have created a function and not called it. so remove the function and just write the code there

Comment: Warning: You have duplicate IDs. If you are outputting elements in a `foreach` loop, you should NEVER have an `id` attribute (unless you have some incrementing iterator, but that becomes impossible to keep track of.

Comment: You have not declared `$p , $b ,$m, $qua, $price, $q` in your php code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
total = parseInt(price) * parseInt(quantity);
```

This will convert your val() strings to integers to make possible math operations. If have floats use parseFloat() instead parseInt();

Comment: please explain your answer as well.. :-)

Comment: In the case of price, parseFloat is probably better. It is less likely for quantity, but still possible.

Comment: `*` casts input to number anyway.

Comment: * for fetch all rows data

Answer (score 1):

first convert values to the specific type and then do multiplication.
`function calTotal() {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr'),
        price    = parseFloat($row.find('.price').val());
        quantity = parseInt($row.find('.quantity').val());
        total =price * quantity;
        console.log("Total is " + total);
}`

Comment: can i call class name within php

Comment: I don't know about php but I thought problem is in your javascript code.

Comment: As I have said twice now, *`*` casts input to numbers anyway*

Answer (score 0):

First you have to convert the value or input to `number` using `parseInt()`or using `parseFloat()` method. Something like this would work

```
function calTotal() {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr'),
        price    = $row.find('.price').val();
        quantity = $row.find('.quantity').val();
        total =parseInt(price) * parseInt(quantity);
        //total= parseFloat(price) * parseFloat(quantity); this can be used also
        console.log("Total is " + total);
}
```

Comment: can i call class name within php

Comment: Do you get these data from a form or what ?? What isnt working actually ??

Comment: `*` casts input to number anyway.

Comment: in php i want to edit mutiple row where multiplication also done automatically

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol that statement would be ultimate, i might edit my answer.